# Why won't my pool find my miners?

Tags: miner-configuration, antminer, raspberry-pi

My main devices: 12x U1 AntMiner + Raspberry Pi B 512 MB (Included 32GB SD containing MinePeon)

As normal I should:

1. Plug in those miners & Raspberry Pi's micro USB-cable into hubs
2. Connect the hubs to Raspberry Pi
3. Connect R-Pi to the internet (88 MBit/s, if it's important)

It should start from here, where I could setup my pool but none of my miners were found.

P.S. I'm sure that cable and software are OK (Checked 4 times)

Comment: I had the same problem.
The problem was the usb hub that wasnt recognized by the raspberry pi.

Comment: What hubs are you using? How are they connected?

Comment: And have u resolved it?